# django foreign key filtering in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)

class District(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

I would like to filter the admin panel by city (selected city). in order to filter too much similar districts names.

If someone has another way to do it no problem, that was a junior try, waiting for your advice.

Comment: which admin did you want to have the city filter on?  check out the docs and try to precise your question https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/filters/

Comment: thank you, the document sent was to helpful.